# counting rows in a column and making a new column out of it in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rowcount

I wish to count no of rows in a column, make a new column out of the data and then plot that new column against an already existent column in the file.

I already wrote some part of the script as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sys import argv
from pylab import *


import csv



script, filename = argv


# read flash.dat to a list of lists
datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./flash.dat").readlines()]

# write it as a new CSV file
with open("./flash.dat", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(datContent)

def your_func(row):
    return (len(dataframe.axes[0]))



columns_to_keep = ['#time']
dataframe = pd.read_csv("./flash.csv", usecols=columns_to_keep)


dataframe['time_interval(dt)'] = dataframe['#time'].diff()

dataframe

dataframe['rowcount'] = dataframe.apply(your_func, axis=1)

dataframe.plot(x='rowcount', y='time_interval(dt)', style='r')

print dataframe

show()
```

Now the problem is, it gives me total no of rows at once , rather not counting row by row increments, the very left column in my output does have the incremental row count, but I cannot label it, hence cannot use to plot. Some output lines is here:

```
              #time  time_interval(dt)  rowcount
0      0.000000e+00                NaN     10216
1      1.000000e-07       1.000000e-07     10216
2      2.200000e-07       1.200000e-07     10216
3      3.640000e-07       1.440000e-07     10216
4      5.368000e-07       1.728000e-07     10216
5      7.441600e-07       2.073600e-07     10216
6      9.929920e-07       2.488320e-07     10216
7      1.291590e-06       2.985984e-07     10216
8      1.649908e-06       3.583181e-07     10216
9      2.079890e-06       4.299817e-07     10216
10     2.595868e-06       5.159780e-07     10216
11     3.215042e-06       6.191736e-07     10216
```

I guess, If I want to plot the data `'time interval_(dt)'` against the new column `'rowcount'`, I somehow have to create a loop or maybe an array which saves no of rows as it reads the data row-wise. I am sharing the file here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4jbxmln9e83355/flash.dat?dl=0

please help me make the column which takes the row count. thanks.

Comment: When you say the very left column would suffice, I'm assuming you mean the index.  If I'm right then `dataframe.plot(y='time_interval(dt)', style='r', use_index=True)` should work

Comment: great ! works good for now. Can you please let me know how I can narrow the range of index, it goes from 0 tp 10,000, what if I want to focus in the range 4000-6000, is there any function for that?

Comment: Use [.iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)  like `dataframe.iloc[4000:6000].plot(y='time_interval(dt)', style='r', use_index=True)`

Comment: again great & thanks

Comment: No problem, happy to help